# Did the AVL attempt to intervene in Gru's attempt to steal the moon?

Tags: despicable-me

In Despicable Me 2, Silas Ramsbottom, director the of [Anti-Villain League](https://despicableme.fandom.com/wiki/Anti-Villain_League) states their mission:

> SILAS:
> An ultra-secret organization dedicated to fighting crime on a global scale. Rob a bank? We're not interested. Kill someone? Not our deal. But you want to melt the polar ice caps? Or vaporize Mt. Fuji? Or even steal the moon? Then we notice.
>
> GRU:
> First of all, you’ve got no proof that I did that. Second, after I did do that, I put it back!
>
> SILAS:
> We’re well aware of that, Mr. Gru. That’s why we’ve brought you here.

Silas is clearly referencing the moon heist from the first film, but, there is no indication that *they actually noticed* (or attempted to do anything about it).

[image]

Is there any reconciliation of this matter in other materials, commentaries, etc...?

*(obviously, out of universe, the AVL didn't yet exist so of course there was no indication in the first film)*

Comment: It's hard to estimate how long the moon was missing for, but it could only have been about an hour or two. It's possible they *intended* to intervene, but the whole thing was over before they could do so.

Comment: yeah @F1Krazy - except, Silas says "you *want* to [sic] steal the moon, then we notice" - the implication to me is that he is saying the AVL will find out and deal with it prior to it actually happening